# Web.xml Security Constraints not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web.xml

Trying to get the security aspect of my web app up and going.

I've created a dynamic web application within eclipse and am trying to use a form based authentication setup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
 <display-name>Application</display-name>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
  <param-value>com.foo.bar.webservices.MyApplication</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
  <param-value>/resteasy</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet>
  <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>httpAuth.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/resteasy/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>/login.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 <security-constraint>
  <display-name>Authorized Only</display-name>
  <web-resource-collection>
   <web-resource-name>Authorized Only</web-resource-name>
   <url-pattern>/restricted/*</url-pattern>
   <http-method>GET</http-method>
   <http-method>PUT</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
   <description>Allowed users</description>
   <role-name>USER</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
  <user-data-constraint>
   <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
 <login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <form-login-config>
   <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
   <form-error-page>/logonError.jsp</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
 </login-config>
 <security-role>
  <role-name>USER</role-name>
 </security-role>
</web-app>
```

However, when I deploy and go to `http://localhost:8080/Application/restricted/index.jsp` it shows, which it shouldn't do.

EDIT 1:  Have made change to remove /Application.  Doing so does not hold on pages such as /restricted/index.jsp

### Folder Breakdown

```
Application
   +build
   -WebContent
     +css
     +img
     +js
     login.jsp
     logonError.jsp
    +META-INF
    -restricted
      index.jsp
    +WEB-INF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are applying the wrong *url-pattern*. Try changing this

```
<url-pattern>/Application/restricted/*</url-pattern>
```

by this

```
<url-pattern>/restricted/*</url-pattern>
```

Answer (score 0):

In our organization, we use security annotations.  From my experience, it's been fairly easy and straightforward to setup and implement.  We happen to use IBM WebSphere for our application server, but security annotations can be used in any server that supports Java EE 5.

Oracle has a good article on this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/security-annotation-142276.html

Search for "Java security annotations" on the web for more info.

Answer (score 0):

For your servlet mapping you are using this pattern:

```
<url-pattern>/resteasy/*</url-pattern>
```

But for the security constraint you are using this pattern:

```
<url-pattern>/Application/restricted/*</url-pattern>
```

These have to match.

I can only assume that this web app is not running from the ROOT context but from the `/Application` root.  The patterns in the web.xml are anchored at the context, so you should drop `/Application` prefix from the `url-pattern`.

Comment: Correct.

The index.jsp page is under http://localhost:8080/Application/login.jsp and then I have my restricted information in 

http://localhost:8080/Application/restricted/index.jsp

Comment: @PSU_Kardi. Is `/Application` your context name? And, BTW, you cannot have `index.jsp` under `localhost:8080/Application/login.jsp`.

Comment: Making that change has the logon form popup when I go to /restricted ; however, it does not apply to the files underneathe i.e. restricted/index.jsp

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing access via a browser, then a `<security-constraint>` can appear to not be working if you've previously logged into Google in that browser. The login can be persistent and may be getting picked up. It's worth checking a URL in a different browser - you may find that the security then works.