# tomcat and security-constraint: url pattern not working

Tags: authentication, tomcat, web.xml, url-pattern

I have 2 apps deployed to a tomcat server. One of them (app2) I want to be protected by tomcat.

Example of the resulting URLs:

```
localhost:8080/app1
localhost:8080/app2
```

i do **not** develop the apps itself, so i have no access to the application specific web.xml of the apps themselves.
So I'm using the "global" one in the /conf folder of tomcat. This is what I added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee                       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0">

  <security-constraint>
    <display-name>app2 Users</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>app2 Content</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/app2/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <security-role>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
  </security-role>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  </login-config>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>debug</param-name>
      <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>listings</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>fork</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <!-- mime type mappings -->
</web-app>
```

IMHO this is all whats nessecary to protect app2, but i do not get a password promt, and app2 is accessible without basic auth. Here is the log:

```
15-Jul-2020 14:58:35.663 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke Security checking request GET /blabla2/
15-Jul-2020 14:58:35.664 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[blabla Content]' against GET /index.jsp --> false
15-Jul-2020 14:58:35.664 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[blabla Content]' against GET /index.jsp --> false
15-Jul-2020 14:58:35.664 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[blabla Content]' against GET /index.jsp --> false
15-Jul-2020 14:58:35.664 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[blabla Content]' against GET /index.jsp --> false
15-Jul-2020 14:58:35.665 FINE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.findSecurityConstraints   No applicable constraint located
```

when setting the `url-pattern` to `/*` everything works, but (as expected) app1 is protected to.
Whats wrong with my `url-pattern`?

Comment: please give more config as we don't see if it's correct or not. Particularly you need to check if you correctly configured a context for app2 at the Host level of your server.xml as explained here [Defining a context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context)

Comment: I did not add an explicit context. Is this nessecary? I Updated the web.xml in the question, but its the "default" web.xml delivered with tomcat

Comment: After reading your remark again: I checked the server.xml and its the default also: I just added the ldap realm. The host section is default without any context defined.

Answer (score 1):

The web.xml is only for server-wide configuration. You couldn't define settings that are related to just one deployment/context.

Since security-constraint work on deployment level, settings like url-pattern are related to the deployment web root.

Example:

```
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Authorized Only</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Authorized Only</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

Would block /app1/hello and /app2/hello.

If you would like to add authorization to just one deployment, you have to set this setting inside the configuration of the deployment.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17948661/8087167 for an other example.